Client error '401 Unauthorized' from USPTO
when I use
PublishedApplication.objects.get("US20130228431A1").claims_text
get HTTPStatusError: Client error '401 Unauthorized' for url 'https://ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/searches/searchWithBeFamily'

I assume you know this is not a way to communicate with the USPTO.

You should post this as an issue in the github for that library, which I think is: https://github.com/parkerhancock/patent_client
